# spring mvc post refuses json

Tags: json, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring-boot 1.1.7.RELEASE and trying to get my POST to work for my controllers.   However, when I submit the html I get the exception:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:98)
```

I believe that Spring-Boot will pickup the HttpMediaType automatically and handle the json requests/reponse.  Certainly all my GET's seem to be working.

Here is my Controller:

```
@Controller
@Transactional
@RequestMapping("/{officeName}/office")
public class OfficeController extends BaseController {

@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public OfficeDTO get(@PathVariable String officeName) {

        return officeDTOConverter.convert( officeService.findByURL( officeName ) );
    }
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public OfficeDTO addOffice(@RequestBody Office office) {

        return officeDTOConverter.convert( officeService.save( office ) );
    }
}
```

And here is my post:
headers:

```
Content-Type    application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

json:

```
{"address":{"addressTypeRefDto":{},"status":"ACTIVE","city":"Glenwood Springs","addressId":2,"seqId":null,"addressLine1":"123 Somewhere Lane","zip":"12345-789","addressLine2":"Suite 100","zipLong":"12345-789","addressLine3":"line 3","state":"CO","addressType":"OFFICE"},"contacts":[{"contactTypeRef":{"contactDescriptionShort":"Office Phone"},"contactId":1,"contactInfo":"555-555-1234","status":0},{"contactTypeRef":{"contactDescriptionShort":"Office Email"},"contactId":2,"contactInfo":"","status":0},{"contactTypeRef":{"contactDescriptionShort":"Office Fax"},"contactId":3,"contactInfo":"","status":0},{"contactTypeRef":{"contactDescriptionShort":"Office Emergency"},"contactId":4,"contactInfo":"","status":0}],"workDays":[{"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","active":"true","startTime":"7:00","endTime":"7:00","breakStartTime":"7:00","breakEndTime":"7:00"},{"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","active":"true","startTime":"7:00","endTime":"7:00","breakStartTime":"7:00","breakEndTime":"7:00"},{"dayOfWeek":"WEDNESDAY","active":"true","startTime":"7:00","endTime":"7:00","breakStartTime":"7:00","breakEndTime":"7:00"},{"dayOfWeek":"THURSDAY","active":"true","startTime":"7:00","endTime":"7:00","breakStartTime":"7:00","breakEndTime":"7:00"},{"dayOfWeek":"FRIDAY","active":"true","startTime":"7:00","endTime":"7:00","breakStartTime":"7:00","breakEndTime":"7:00"},{"dayOfWeek":"SATURDAY","active":"true","startTime":"7:00","endTime":"7:00","breakStartTime":"7:00","breakEndTime":"7:00"},{"dayOfWeek":"SUNDAY","active":"true","startTime":"7:00","endTime":"7:00","breakStartTime":"7:00","breakEndTime":"7:00"}],"officeType":"GENERAL","officePhone":"555-555-1234","name":"Office Name","uRL":"test","status":"ACTIVE","servicePackageType":"BASIC","languageId":"English","ein":"123"}
```

and the response:

```
{"timestamp":1417717964314,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported","path":"/mycompany/office"}
```

I am using the GET json to populate the html, and then taking those values to build a json string to submit via KendoUI:

```
 transport : {
                read : {
                    type : "POST",
                    beforeSend: function(req) {
                           req.setRequestHeader('Accept', "application/json");
                    },
                    url : function(options) {
                    return "/" + officeURL + "/office"
                    },
                    beforeSend: function(xhr){
                            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
                    },
                    contentType : "application/json",
                    dataType : 'json'
                },
                parameterMap : function(data, type) {
                    if (type == "read") {
                    return createOfficeJSON();
                    }
                }
```

If anyone sees any reason why the media type is being rejected, or if I have a mistake somewhere I would appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: In the json when you are specifying times and the such(startTime and endTime for example) do you have 2 setter methods one that takes date and one that takes string? Have you tried creating an example post method that just takes a map? For example I was able to make this post work with your mediatype and your provided JSON                                                                             @ResponseBody
 @RequestMapping(value="test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String testPost(@RequestBody HashMap<String, Object> blarg) {
        return "GOOD JOB";
 }

Comment: @Zergleb, Thank you for the quick response.  I tried adding setters for all the LocalTimes, so that WorkDay class has one that accepts LocalTime and another that takes a String.  Unfortunately I still got the same exception. I was able to add a new POST method that successfully took a HashMap, which seems to indicate that its not really a media type issue as a mapping issue?

Comment: No I think 2 setters would cause a problem. Have you tried just one that takes a string? I think I had heard of this problem before and it seems like that might have been it.

Comment: Were you able to come out of this issue, I am also currently facing this issue on my service